# Syntax error on fielddefinition

Tags: c#, sql

I'm trying to create a table in my database through C# using the following method:

```
    private static void CreateTables()
    {
        _commandtext = "CREATE TABLE Users(" +
                        "ID Integer PRIMARY KEY, " +
                        "Username Text(20), " +
                        "Password Text(25), " +
                        "IBAN Text(18)" +
                        ");";
        _command = new OleDbCommand(_commandtext, _connection);

        _connection.Open();

        int number = _command.ExecuteNonQuery();  <<< Error

        _connection.Close();
    }
```

Somehow it returns an error: "Syntaxerror in fielddefinition"
What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Solved but nevertheless: I'm using this for Access

Comment: Does it really contain no more information than that? And I wouldn't expect it to be "syntaxerror" and "fielddefinition". Please copy and paste the *exact* error message.

Comment: if this is for SQL Server (or any other DBMS I know of) you should use `varchar(20)` or `nvarchar(20)` instead of `text(20)`. `Text` is a deprecated datatype for a lot of text.

Comment: Also, tell us what RDBMS you're using

Comment: `Username` and `Password` are reserved for some DBMS that's the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried adding square brackets around your names?

```
private static void CreateTables()
{
    _commandtext = "CREATE TABLE [Users](" +
                    "[ID] Integer PRIMARY KEY, " +
                    "[Username] Text(20), " +
                    "[Password] Text(25), " +
                    "[IBAN] Text(18)" +
                    ");";
    _command = new OleDbCommand(_commandtext, _connection);

    _connection.Open();

    int number = _command.ExecuteNonQuery();  <<< Error

    _connection.Close();
}
```

Maybe your DB thinks you're referencing other fields instead of creating new ones with the names you put in.

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks for the unbelievably quick response/solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SQL Server you should try:

```
_commandtext = "CREATE TABLE Users(" +
               "ID Integer PRIMARY KEY, " +
               "Username VARCHAR(20), " +
               "[Password] VARCHAR(25), " +
               "IBAN VARCHAR(18)" +
               ");";
```